# Oracle database reads monitor or counter

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm not very familiar with Oracle DB. Is there a way to see all of the record reads on all tables across the DB? A tool/utility of some sort maybe, or somehow built into Oracle Sql Developer?

I'm doing this to see if there's any inefficient queries in the application, or to see who's the biggest "hog" of DB reads across the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a **lot** of different possibilities here depending on how detailed (and pretty) you want to get, your licensing, what infrastructure you have in place, etc.

The simplest, lowest common denominator option from within SQL Developer would be to open the Reports menu (View | Reports), go to All Reports | Data Dictionary Reports | Database Administration | Top SQL and select one of the reports there.  Probably Top SQL by Buffer Gets or Top SQL by CPU.  Those will open a report that will show the top SQL by logical I/O or CPU that is currently in the plan cache.

[image: Screen Shot of SQL Developer Reports view]